# "Recovery" partition is deleted

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, asus-laptop, partition-recovery, recovery-partition

I deleted the partition named "Recovery" from my ASUS laptop. How to get it back? If doesn't have this partition, any problem cause to my laptop?

Comment: Are you sure it’s gone? What happens if you reboot and press `Alt+F10` on the first black screen. If that doesn’t work, try `Alt+F11`.

Comment: Asus laptops usually use F9 to boot into recovery

Answer (score 2):

[Go to this page](http://us.estore.asus.com/)

Type: Recovery into the search box on the right, hit enter, it will list all recovery media, you will have to look for yours on the pages it returns in the search., they are specific to each system or model.

If you are outside the US, [use this page to load the proper store front](http://shop.asus.com/), then do the search.

Answer (score 1):

> How to get it back?

Perhaps you have a recovery CD/DVD that will replace it when doing a full restore (and overwriting all your important data)

Perhaps ASUS website allows you to download an ISO or purchase a recovery CD/DVD?

> If doesn't have this partition, any problem cause to my laptop?

Not until you accidentally destroy something important and need to make your computer usable again.